# Image size changes on reloading the web page

Tags: html, css, angular

Hi I have a very weird problem. I have built an angular app and as a part of it one of the components have an image displayed

This is the code

.html

```
<div flexLayout="row">
      <div fxFlex="50%">
        <img src="../../assets/building.png" class="building" usemap="#buildingMap">
      </div>
</div>
```

.css

```
.building {
    height: 510px;
}
```

So the problem is for first-time when I open the page the height of the image is maintained but width is compressed. And then when I reload the page width is adjusted to occupy the div. Does anyone know why is it happening this way?

Comment: I find that with images if you have a fixed `height` setting `width: auto;` keeps the aspect ratio.